# Audit tables: Each field for table or one table

Tags: database, audit

Everything is fine in my project except with the audit fields. Just insert and update is being audited in our imaginary universe.

I proposed one table like similar to the next examples:

- [best design for a changelog / auditing database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201527/best-design-for-a-changelog-auditing-database-table)
- [Suggestions for implementing audit tables in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823/suggestions-for-implementing-audit-tables-in-sql-server)
  Just table name, table column, user, action and date.

But my team didn't think the same way, they put a column on each table to track an update or insert time. And when I asked *why?* they told me that is the way that they keep the track in their work.

In the end I give up and I put every field on each table. Since all the team except me, told me to put that fields.

Example:

Their approach

```
Table Customer
+-------------+-------------+-----+--------------------------------+-------------+
| Name        | LastName    | ... | LastModification (Audit Field) | User        |
+-------------+-------------+-----+--------------------------------+-------------+
| varchar(30) | varchar(50) | ... | datetime                       | varchar(30) |
+-------------+-------------+-----+--------------------------------+-------------+
```

My approach

```
Table Customer
+-------------+-------------+-----+
| Name        | LastName    | ... |
+-------------+-------------+-----+
| varchar(30) | varchar(50) | ... |
+-------------+-------------+-----+

Table Audit
+-----------+------------+--------+------+-------------+
| TableName | TableField | Action | User | DateAndTime |
+-----------+------------+--------+------+-------------+
```

So the question is:

Which is a better design, one table that keep the history of transactions or one field for each table? (Pro and cons)

Comment: In their solution, do they only maintain a single copy of the row with the last UPDATE time, or do they maintain multiple versions of the row?

Comment: @LarryLustig : A copy? they add the column to the table. Not copies at all. Just a last modified field.

Comment: The "their" approach provides semantic auditing on a per-row basis, whereas the "your" approach only does this on a per-table basis.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> Which is a better design, one table that keep the history of
>   transactions or one field for each table? (Pro and cons)

Rather than focus on the 2 choices here's a answer on the 4 approaches I've worked with over the years. Each with its pros and cons.

### 1. Just three fields

Just add three fields (last action, time_stamp, update_user) to every table and call it a day.

**Pros** Super easy. Performs well

**Cons** You can't report on data you don't have, so this structure tells you almost nothing (except for deletes)

### 2. Clone table

Each table has a copy plus the three audit fields and every time a user changes a record the audit table gets inserted into.

**Pros** Performs pretty well. Easy to create a row by row history that the user can dig through.

**Cons**

- Every change to the base table needs a corresponding change to the audit table.
- If the users don't want a row by row history to dig through and they want a report of what exactly changed it can get nasty in a hury. See the answers to [How can I write a query to extract individual changes from snapshots of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741527/how-can-i-write-a-query-to-extract-individual-changes-from-snapshots-of-data)

### 3. History Table only

There's no base table only a history table.
This is basically the same as Clone Table except now you have to always get the current record.

**Pros** Pros of 2 but everything's an insert. Less maintenance then the option 2.

**Cons** You'll end up losing the maintenance gain because you'll end up maintaining views or you'll be sprinkling get-the-current-record logic all over the place

### 4. Generic audit table

This table has four columns ( Table*, Column_name, old_value, new_value ) and the three audit fields.

**Pros** Easy to set up and maintain.

**Cons**

- Its unintuitive but it takes up a lot of space because your `old_value` and `new_value` fields have to be `nvarchar(max)` or equivalent so it can accept anything that's in your base table.
- Performs poorly on reads and writes.
- Its a pain to set up a row by row history report
- If there's any kind of workflow in the records audit reporting can become non-trivial. For example you get a requirement that users only want to see changes that occur after the status on the records becomes 'approved'. That's hard even in options 2 and 3 but becomes a disaster in the Generic audit approach.

### **Summary**

I prefer #2 the Clone table approach as it seems to work best for me. I've had issues with #1 being insufficient and #4 can be a serious perf nightmare that requires a lot of work to undo.

Comment: Hi, you said you prefer second approach. From the question the `AuditTable` has column TableField which was changed/affected. What if I change more than one column in a table? Should I add more rows to the `AuditTable`? Is there another approach of doing so? Can the audit table stay independent or should I make a relation with other tables by some way?

Comment: I'm going for option 2. I eliminated the cons by A. scripting the generation of the table clones and B. standardize the clone table by using fields: id, timestamp, user, action (I, U, D), old_data (jsonb). This way, the clone does not need to change when the master table changes fields.

Comment: @christiaanwesterbeek two things. Jsonb is only available for postgres and it sounds like you've done something very difficult to report on. Consider what you would need to do to determine when a particular field value changed.

Comment: In Option #2, how we can optimise query when we want snapshot of each user at particular time in the past? I mean group by user and then take last item of each user.

Comment: Temporal tables are another great option introduced with SQL Server 2016.